# Initialise of semaphore in C

Tags: c

My task is to initialise the semaphore and the semaphore should be allocated in the SharedMem structure

```
typedef struct{
    int shmid;
    sem_t sem;
} SharedMem;
```

I create shared memory like this:

```
int shmid = shmget(sharedMemKey, sizeof(SharedMem), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
if(shmid < 0){
printf("Shared memory could not be created.\n");
return 1;
}
SharedMem *shm = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
if(shm == (SharedMem *) -1){
 printf("Shared memory could not be created.\n");
return 1;
}
shm->shmid = shmid;
```

When I use &shm, it shows error `sem_init(&shm, 0, 1);` I dont know what else to use here.

Thanks for any ideas

Comment: [mcve] and the messages you are seeing on the console need to be displayed here.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a pointer to a `SharedMem` to a function expecting a pointer to a sempaphore id (`sem_t`).

So instead of this:

```
sem_init(&shm, 0, 1);
```

This:

```
sem_init(&shm->sem, 0, 1);
```

Comment: Thank you, but now it prints the first error

Comment: You're lucky I got this far with the limited amount of information  you provided.  You need to provide a [mcve] and specify verbatim the errors you are getting from your build.